# What are the limit points of set $E=\left\{ a_{n}\::\:n=1,\:2,\:3,\:\cdots\right\} $, $a_{n}=\frac{n-1}{n+1}\left|\sin\frac{n\pi}{7}\right|$

Tags: general-topology, limsup-and-liminf

Find the limit points of the following sequence:

Take the sequence:$$a_{n}=\frac{n-1}{n+1}\left|\sin\frac{n\pi}{7}\right|$$

We wish to find:
a. the limit points
b. $\underline{\lim}_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_{n}$, and $\overline{\lim}_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_{n}$
My attempt:
When $\frac{n\pi}{7}=k\pi$, i.e, $n=7k$, $k$ are integers, then
we have $\underline{\lim}_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_{n}=0$

When $\frac{n\pi}{7}=\frac{\pi}{2}+k\pi$, i.e, $n=7\left(k+\frac{1}{2}\right)$,
$k$ are integers, then we have $\overline{\lim}_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_{n}=1$

Is that correct?

How to find the limit points? Thank you very much

Comment: $n$ and $k$ are supposed to be integers, so $n = 7 (k + 1/2)$ is impossible.

Comment: Hint: $\sin(n\pi/7)$ has $7$ possible values for integers $n$.

Comment: oh yes correct. thank you. Then what is $\overline{\lim}_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_{n}$

Comment: take every $mod7$ integer $n$ and find the limit...This is a limit point for $a_n$

Comment: mod7 integer n and find the limit. I do not know how to do it. Could you please explain ?

Answer (score 2):

Note that

$$\left\{\left\vert \sin\dfrac{n\pi}{7}\right\vert \ ; \ n \in \mathbb N\right\} \subseteq \{0, \sin \dfrac{\pi}{7},\sin \dfrac{2\pi}{7}, \sin \dfrac{3\pi}{7}\}=A$$

As $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{n-1}{n+1}= 1$, the set $L$ of limit points of $\{a_n \ ; \ n\in \mathbb N\}$ is included in $A$. By picking appropriate subsequences, you can prove that $L=A$.

Then $\liminf a_n =0$ and $\limsup a_n = \sin \dfrac{3\pi}{7}$.

Answer (score 0):

If $n=7m+k$, $k=0,1,2,3,4,5,6$ then $\left|\sin\frac{(7m+k)\pi}{7}\right|=sin(k\pi/7)$. But also $lim\frac{n-1}{n+1}=1$,so the available limit points are: $sin(k\pi/7)$. What is the biggest and smallest of these values? these are upper and lower limit points you are looking for.

Comment: $p$ is a limit point of $E$ if for every $\epsilon>0$, $\left(N_{\epsilon}\left(p\right)\setminus\left\{ p\right\} \right)\cap E\neq\emptyset$.
how to prove those points are limit points ?

Comment: These points are limits of  no fixed subsequences of $a_n$.

Comment: For example if $b_n=1$ then the lower and upper limit points are equal to 1, but the set image of  $b_n$ has no limit points...

Comment: i am confused. i think limit point of a set, and lim inf, lim sup are different concepts.
I think this is the definition of limit point of a set. $p$ is a limit point of $E$ if for every $\epsilon>0$, $\left(N_{\epsilon}\left(p\right)\setminus\left\{ p\right\} \right)\cap E\neq\emptyset$

Comment: You are right, they are different.

Comment: then how to prove sin(kπ/7), k=0,1,2,3,4,5,6  are limit points by using the definition ?

Comment: for $k=0$ it is not as $a_n=0$, for the other cases they are...